# How do I filter the results of a v-for loop in VueJS with a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am trying to use a computed property in order to filter the results that are being displayed when using a v-for loop. However, I still see all the bars that are decleared in my bars.js on my application. I was expecting to only see one as it is set to 'true'. Therefore, where am I goinf wrong? Any help welcome.

I am following https://medium.com/devmarketer/how-to-add-conditional-statements-to-v-for-loops-in-vue-js-c0b4d17e7dfd

```
<li v-for="bar in bars" :key="bar.id">
    <h2>{{ bar.barName }}</h2>
</li> 


<script>
import bars from "./../data/bars";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bars:  bars
    };
  },
  computed: {
      bars: function() {
        return this.default.filter(function(u) {
          return u.newListing
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In an additional file called bars.js I have the following;

```
export default [
    {
        barName: "Mikes",
        newListing: true,
    },
    {
        barName: "Cheers",
        newListing: false,
    },
    {
        barName: "Biker Bar",
        newListing: false,
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `bars` in your code, so it's not clear which the template should use. It looks like it's opting for the `bars` in `data`. You should rename the computed property to something unique and then us that in the template. For example:

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        bars:  [/* your bar data goes here */]
      };
    },
    computed: {
        bars_filtered: function() {
          return this.bars.filter(u => u.newListing)
      }
    }
  };
```

Then in your template you would loop over `bars_filtered`:

`v-for="bar in bars_filtered"`

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I think I understand why your answer works now. I can see how it is getting the list of bars, but assigning this to a new function which now has a condition set against it. Your solution works, so thank you so much for helping.